# Why do I always have to restart the Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

Every time I change anything, I have to restart the server for it to take effect. But that wasn't always the case, it used to work normally before, when I changed anything, it used to get updated automatically.. what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails uses `config.cache_classes` to determine whether it should or should not reload your application classes on each request.

You should ensure it is set to `false` in your `development.rb` file (or whatever environment you actually use).